# Probability question for an employee raffle

Tags: probability

We are holding an employee raffle and there's one big prize that everyone wants.  There are 145 people in the pool.  We want to give the big prize at the end to build suspense but an employee said we should give it at the beginning because it's not fair as people's odds to win the prize aren't even.

Is that a true statement? Obviously if we give the prize at the beginning then nobody would care after that.

Comment: It's a loaded statement about conditional probability. Without getting into the details, can I just suggest that you *draw* in the order that makes this person happy, but *reveal* in the order that you want? So the big winner will be determined first, but you will announce it last.

Answer (score 0):

Before the raffle begins, the probability of any employee winning any specific prize is 1/145 = .0069.
Changing the order of the raffle does not effect this probability in any way.